# Caught unexpected exception org.hibernate.QueryException

Tags: hibernate, exception, liferay

So here is the code :

```
    public static List<Zahtev> getZahtevSearchContainerList(RenderRequest request, Long groupId, SearchContainer<Zahtev> searchContainer, Criterion permanentCriterion) throws SystemException {
        int start = (searchContainer!=null) ? searchContainer.getStart() : QueryUtil.ALL_POS;
        int end = (searchContainer!=null) ? searchContainer.getEnd() : QueryUtil.ALL_POS;
        Criterion criterion = null;
        if(statusId == 0){
            try {
                Status statusP = StatusLocalServiceUtil.getStatussByOpis("Predato");
                Status statusO = StatusLocalServiceUtil.getStatussByOpis("Odustanak od nabavke");
                Criterion criterion1 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("status", statusP.getId());
                criterion1 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.and(criterion1, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("vrednost", 0.0));
                criterion1 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion1, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.ne("status", statusP.getId()));

                Criterion criterion2 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("status", statusO.getId());
                Calendar fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                fromDate.setTime(new Date());
                fromDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                fromDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                fromDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                fromDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                criterion2 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.and(criterion2, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.gt("datumRokaZaPredaju", fromDate.getTime()));
                criterion2 = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion2, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.ne("status", statusO.getId()));

                criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.and(criterion1, criterion2);
            } catch (NoSuchStatusException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("status", statusId);
        }
        query = null;
        try {
            // String sortByType = ParamUtil.getString(request, "orderByType"); 
            query = createQuery(request, groupId, permanentCriterion);
            String newSortByCol = getSortColumnName("zahtev");
            if ( newSortByCol!=null ) {
                //if ( newSortByCol.equalsIg

noreCase(sortByCol) ) ascending = !ascending;
            query.addOrder( ascending ? OrderFactoryUtil.asc(newSortByCol) : OrderFactoryUtil.desc(newSortByCol));
        } else {
            for ( String s : mainOrderColumns ) {
                query.addOrder(OrderFactoryUtil.asc(s));
            }
        }
        query.setLimit(start, end);
        if(criterion!= null)
            query.add(criterion);
        return (List<Zahtev>) ZahtevLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    query = null;

    if ( zahtevGroupSensitive ) return (List<Zahtev>) ZahtevLocalServiceUtil.getZahtevsByGroupId(groupId, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd());
    return (List<Zahtev>) ZahtevLocalServiceUtil.getAll(start, end);
}
```

When i start server it works fine for a while, but at some point error appear :
ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-10][BasePersistenceImpl:202] Caught unexpected exception org.hibernate.QueryException
And then it stops. When i restart server again it works fine for a while again.
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Please give a hint in which line you get the exception. Is there a message in the exception?

Comment: No just this : ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-10][BasePersistenceImpl:202] Caught unexpected exception org.hibernate.QueryException.